# Low sound issues on HP p7-1227c PC using IDT 92HD73E1X5 chip

Tags: sound, alsa, troubleshooting

Anyone else ever encountered issues with low sound?

Installed a fresh new install of ubuntu 12.04 x64 alongside Win7. Everything runs great except for the sound.

Computer is a [hp pavilion p7-1227c](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/Document.jsp?objectID=c03348828&lang=en&cc=us&taskId=110&contentType=SupportFAQ&prodSeriesId=5187022&prodTypeId=12454).

**What i've tried:**

- I've also tried adding the latest audio ppa.
- reinstalling `alsa` and `alsa-mixer`
- Check the settings in system -> sound
- Attempted to unmute and amplify the speakers, headset etc
- Modified settings in `pavucontrol`
- Attempted this solution: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/271519

Also, this is my alsa output: http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=de7e2bfb645f4fa5c2687ad6742d7ccdfb8fe6ec

Any ideas? I just installed a new install of ubuntu 12.04 on this particular computer.

**aplay -l:**

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 0: STAC92xx Analog [STAC92xx Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 1: STAC92xx Digital [STAC92xx Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

**lsmod | grep snd**

> snd_hda_codec_idt      70795  1  snd_hda_intel          33773  3 
>   snd_hda_codec         127706  2 snd_hda_codec_idt,snd_hda_intel
>   snd_hwdep              13668  1 snd_hda_codec snd_pcm
>   97188  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec snd_seq_midi           13324  0 
>   snd_rawmidi            30748  1 snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event
>   14899  1 snd_seq_midi snd_seq                61896  2
>   snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event snd_timer              29990  2
>   snd_pcm,snd_seq snd_seq_device         14540  3
>   snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq snd                    78855  15
>   snd_hda_codec_idt,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hwdep,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq,snd_timer,snd_seq_device
>   soundcore              15091  1 snd snd_page_alloc         18529  2
>   snd_hda_intel,snd_pcm

**lspci -v | grep -A7 -i "audio"**

```
00:14.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Hudson Azalia Controller (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 2ae0
    Flags: bus master, slow devsel, latency 32, IRQ 16
    Memory at feb40000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd-hda-intel
```

Comment: Filed a support request here too: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/1041322

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been working on this problem for a couple of days now.  I have a work around posted in this forum :

[Bug #1041322](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/1041322)

It looks like the HDA sound driver is not setting up the EAPD bit correctly when it detects  speakers plugged into the "green" jack.   If you are just using stereo speakers, plugging them into the Orange "Center" channel seems to get around this.  Otherwise there is a hack you can do with the a utility (hda-verb) described in my post to set the EAPD bit to the correct state.

Next step is to see why the driver does this in the first place.

Comment: Thanks. So just plugging it into the orange jack in the rear of the computer should solve this for now? Also, would i have to do anything for the orange jack to work?

Comment: In my tests,  plugging my stereo speakers into the orange center channel jack works with no other changes required.  Of coarse,  you can't use a 5.1 sound system that way but its better than nothing. Try it and see ?  Report back here to either way please ?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed in the upstream ALSA package and updated as of Ubuntu 12.10. Sound on this PC / motherboard doesn't work properly "out of the box".